# Vala string processing corrupts memory. Why and how to avoid?

Tags: glib, vala, memory-corruption

I'm not sure whether I'm misusing Vala or `GLib.Regex`, because I'm new to both. I've created a minimal example, which reproduces the error. From the following code, I'd expect that it prints `a INPUTX b` six times, prefixed with `source` and `result` alternatingly:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void run( string src )
    {
        var regex = new Regex( "INPUT[0-9]" );
        for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
        {
            stdout.printf( @"-- source: $src\n" );
            src = regex.replace( src, -1, 0, "value" );
            stdout.printf( @"-- result: $src\n\n" );
        }
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        Test.run( "a INPUTX b" );
    }
}
```

I wrote this code based on [the example in the docs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/StringSample). However, after compiling with `valac Test.vala --pkg glib-2.0` and running, I get:

```
-- source: a INPUTX b
-- result: a INPUTX b

-- source: -- source: 
-- result: N�

-- source: -- source: 
-- result: PN�
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the generated C code, I concluded that this rather is a Vala-related issue: Vala puts a `g_free` to the end of the loop's body, which frees the memory returned by `g_regex_replace`, and that is referenced by `src`. But why does Vala do that?

The reason is that ([see](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Arrays))

> arguments are, by default, unowned.

Hence, when we assign the `string` object returned by `regex.replace` to the `unowned string src`, that reference is ([see](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Ownership))

> not recorded in the object

and the Vala compile considers it to be safe to dispose - although it's not quiet clear, why this happens particularly at the end of the loop's body.

So the straiht-forward solution is to declare the `src` argument as `owned`.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff: Thanks for your comment. But I think this isn't a bug, is it?

Comment: I think it might be, see the answer I posted now.

Comment: To be clear, the bug is that the compiler accepts the code.  You'll still have to fix your code.

Comment: I don't think that it's a bug because the compiler does what it should according to the docs. Its rather the absence of a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this (nonsense) code:

```
string foo (string s)
{
    return s;
}

void run (string src)
{
    var regex = new Regex( "INPUT[0-9]" );
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i )
    {
        stdout.printf( @"-- source: $src\n" );
        //src = regex.replace( src, -1, 0, "value" );
        src = foo (src);
        stdout.printf( @"-- result: $src\n\n" );
    }
}

void main ()
{
    run( "a INPUTX b" );
}
```

The Vala compiler (rightfully) complains:

```
test.vala:13.2-13.16: error: Invalid assignment from owned expression to unowned variable
        src = foo (src);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So there must be something different for methods from vapi files, since it allows the call to `Regex.replace ()`.

I smell a bug somewhere (either in the compiler or the vapi), but I'm not sure.

Comment: The VAPI is fine; the issue is that the compiler doesn't generate an error when it should.  Seems to be due to the fact that Regex.replace throws an exception (without the exception the error is generated).